How to properly use `cost_filter` argument to apply the budget for resources with specific tags when using `aws_budgets_budget` resource?
I have created multiple resources with certain tags like these:
tags = {
"Environment" = "TEST"
"Project" = "MyProject"
}

And I want to create aws_budgets_budget resource that would track the expenses of the resources that have these two specific tags. I have created the aws_budgets_budget_resource and included cost_filter like this:
resource "aws_budgets_budget" "myproject_budget" {
  name = "my-project-budget"
  budget_type = "COST"
  limit_amount = 30
  limit_unit = "USD"
  time_unit = "MONTHLY"
  time_period_start = "2024-12-01_00:00"
  time_period_end = "2032-01-01_00:00"

  notification {
    comparison_operator = "GREATER_THAN"
    notification_type = "ACTUAL"
    threshold = 75
    threshold_type = "PERCENTAGE"
    subscriber_email_addresses = [ "${var.budget_notification_subscriber_email}" ]
  }

  notification {
    comparison_operator = "GREATER_THAN"
    notification_type = "ACTUAL"
    threshold = 50
    threshold_type = "PERCENTAGE"
    subscriber_email_addresses = [ "${var.budget_notification_subscriber_email}" ]
  }

  cost_filter {
    name = "TagKeyValue"
    values = [ "user:Environment$TEST", "user:Project$MyProject" ]
  }

  tags = {
    "Name" = "my-project-budget"
    "Project" = "MyProject"
    "Environment" = "TEST"
  }
}

But after adding the cost_filter it does not filter out these resources and does not show the expenses. If I eliminate cost_filter argument it shows that I have spent 5 USD out of 30 for this month, but this applies to all the resources and not just specifically with these two tags.
Has anyone encountered this before and has the solution ? What might be the reason for this happening ?

Did you activate the cost allocations tags?

Yes, I did activate them.
